# How to create a new list and write pandas dataframe to it?

Tags: python, pandas

I have already prepared Excel spreadsheet. What would be the best way to create a new list using python code? How can I access it after to write the pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `df.to_excel(filename)` with a target filename will overwrite an existing file. You must use an ExcelWriter and pass this as the first argument to df.to_excel().

**Try this:**

```python
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:    
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')  # open/create dataFrame to add
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='new_sheet3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with that

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
x = np.random.randn(100, 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(x) #creating a random dataframe or using yours
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('flat.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl', mode= 'a')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'y')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```